# Flutter for web, how to convert List<dynamic> to List<Item>?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**Flutter Web**

I get `List<dynamic>` from `json.decode(res.body)`

and can't convert to my expected type `List<Item>`

in chrome dev tool, it will throw

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type 'List<dynamic>' should be 'List<Item>' to implement expected type 'FutureOr<List<Item>>'.
```

here is my code

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  static Future get({String url, Object params}) async {
    final res = await http.get(_root + url);
    return json.decode(res.body);
  }

  /// get 30 items of specific content type
  static Future<List<Item>> getContentList({String type, num page = 1}) async {
    final List<dynamic> ret = await ApiService.get(
      url: _typeMap[type],
    );
    // If I try `ret.cast<Item>()` it will also throw something like `... type _JsonMap ...`
    return ret;
  }
}
```

response body is hacker news item list,

```
[{comments_count: 466,
domain: "github.com",
id: 22925087,
points: 1162,
time: 1587398440,
time_ago: "8 hours ago",
title: "Shirt Without Stripes",
type: "link",
url: "https://github.com/elsamuko/Shirt-without-Stripes",
user: "elsamuko",
}]
```

how can I fix that ?

Comment: Please share your json and your code where you are trying to decode json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the response body should be a List of Maps. To convert it into `List<Item>`, your `Item` class will need a `fromJson` constructor.

```
class Item {
  ...
  Item.fromJson(...)
      : ...
}
```

Look up this link to find out how to how to implement this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79

Then all you have to do is map this function over all the objects in the list.

```
  static Future<List<Item>> getContentList({String type, num page = 1}) async {
    final List<dynamic> ret = await ApiService.get(
      url: _typeMap[type],
    );
    return ret.map((obj) => Item.fromJson(obj)).toList();
  }
```